# Artisan Error: Failed to listen on localhost:8000

Tags: php, laravel-artisan

I'm having a problem starting my Laravel installation. Whenever I type in the terminal `php artisan serve`, I get this error:

> Failed to listen on localhost:8000 (reason:une tentative d'access un
> α socket de maniere interdite par ses autorisation d'access a 0t0
> tent0e)

What's the problem, and how can it be fixed?

[image: img problem]

It's working now I just changed the listen port from 8000 to 8888 or any other port your services don't use.

```
php artisan serve --port="8888"
```

Comment: Did you open the command-prompt with administrator privileges?

Comment: @Yasser First update your driver

Comment: @virbhadrasinh 
driver of what i should update it ??

Comment: @blablabla  yes I steel have the same problem

Comment: @Yasser Network driver because altimatlly all request of the TCp/IP is go via two way one is wifi or Ethernet

Comment: it's works now i just changed the listen port to 8888 
'php artisan serve --port="8888"'

Comment: Go to /var/log/apache2 and delete the error_log and the access_log file

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Are there any other services running on port 8000?

You can use this command on Windows:

```
netstat -aon | more
```

or on Linux / OSX

```
sudo netstat -plnt
```

to see what services are running. Then disable the service that is running on port 8000 or use another port.

Comment: You could also try to use another port with 'php artisan serve --port="8888"'

Comment: It could also be that windows UAC is blocking it. Try to disable UAC. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/turn-user-account-control-on-off

Comment: if you're using linux http://stackoverflow.com/a/36489075/2652524 it solves my problem

Comment: Didn't work → `netstat: lnt: unknown or uninstrumented protocol`

Comment: This worked for me: `netstat -anv | grep LISTEN` — thanks to https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/274841/72599

Answer (score 150):

Fixing Error: Failed to listen on `localhost:8000` (reason: Address already in use)

## List processes with php in it

`ps -ef | grep php`

## Example output

```
501  **9347**     393    0  1:29PM ttys000    0:00.21 php artisan serve
501    9351    **9347**  0  1:29PM ttys000    0:02.01 /usr/local/php5-5.6.14-20151002-085853/bin/php -S localhost:8000 .../laravel/server.php
501    9781       393    0  1:56PM ttys000    0:00.00 grep php
```

## Then kill the process

`kill -9 9347`

Comment: Use kill -9 9347 to force termination of the process.

Comment: This doesn't necessarily work if the application blocking you from using the port isn't php at all but some other application on your system.

Comment: This works if you had a php artisan serve previously and you terminated it wrongly, as I did, for instance, by removing the folder while the server was executing. Then the only way to start serving again on ort 8000 is to kill the previous process.

Comment: thanks my king, very helpful your answer =)

Answer (score 23):

List process using `ps -ef | grep php`

Then **below only works for me**

```
kill -9 9347
```

which is a **force kill of the process**

```
501  9347   393   0  1:29PM ttys000    0:00.21 php artisan serve
```

**Option 2:**

If above not works, Change the default laravel serve port number if you can, like

```
php artisan serve --port=8088
```

Comment: At least in Laravel Framework 8.13.0, Laravel itself will try another port and in my case started serving on 8001

Comment: This works for me. Also has cleaner explaination.

Answer (score 10):

8000 is the default port. Use instead of :

```
php artisan serve --port=8005
```

Answer (score 4):

It is because something already running on that port and you can change the port by command itself, by running following command

```
php artisan serve --port 8001
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `killall -9 php` and if you want to close other services use  `killall -9 node` or `killall -9 mysql`

Comment: `killall -9 php` is very dangerous, for instance, it could kill your PHP storm also. It's better to first search for the process and kill it individually

Answer (score 4):

When **php artisan serve** command given, below mentioned problem occured.

> macridmi1109@Ridmis-MacBook-Pro kcnk % php artisan serve

> Laravel development server started on http://localhost:8000/

> [Thu Aug  6 11:31:10 2020] Failed to listen on localhost:8000 (reason: Address already in use)

Then try this line of code,

> macridmi1109@Ridmis-MacBook-Pro project_laravel % ps -ef | grep php

Result will be,

> 501 66167     1   0 11:24am ttys002    0:00.77 /usr/bin/php -S localhost:8000
> /Users/macridmi1109/Documents/Laravel/project_laravel/server.php

> 501 66268 64261   0 11:31am ttys002    0:00.00 grep php

Finally run the below code and, then again **php artisan serve**

> macridmi1109@Ridmis-MacBook-Pro project_laravel % kill 66167

SOLUTION EXPLAINED BELOW

I use the command, **ps -ef | grep php**. After that, you will be able to find  Process ID. After recognising the correct Process ID, use this command **kill 66167** (kill "Process ID"). Then try **php artisan serve**. This worked for me.

**Happy Coding**

Comment: Great solution.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I found a problem we face several times in Ubuntu.

```
*Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8000 (reason: Address already in use)*
```

What we do, we change the port, right?

```
This problem can be solved also in few seconds following below steps.
1. Open Terminal
2. **sudo su**
3. **netstat -plnt**
_find the process running on port 8080_
4. **kill -9 PROCESSNUMBER**
```

For more details, see my blog, [click here](https://nsmodi.wordpress.com/2019/01/31/laravel-artisan-error-failed-to-listen-on-127-0-0-18000-reason-address-already-in-use/?preview=true&frame-nonce=9df0b008fa)

Comment: From the URL name, it seems like you're affiliated with the URL. If you are, remember that you need to add disclosure. See [how not to be a spammer](/help/promotion)

Comment: This is my own website @zoe

Answer (score 2):

For me, it was silly mistake. I have installed php in new machine but **php.ini was missing**. So, I have created php.ini file from php.ini-production file and then **php artisan serve** command worked fine as expected.

Answer (score 0):

for me php -S localhost:8080 from the terminal in vs code will sometimes crash, but still be running in the background.

-9 to force kill did it for me
thanks @hemss

I did

```
php -S localhost:8080

[Wed Dec 12 13:48:03 2018] Failed to listen on localhost:8080(reason: Address already in use)
```

then I..

```
sudo netstat -plnt
```

find the process running on port 8080

```
tcp        2      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10312/php
```

then force kill it..

```
kill -9 10312
```

I get

```
[1]  + 10312 killed     php -S localhost:8080
```

then restart...

```
php -S localhost:8080
```

Answer (score 0):

best way if you 8000 port is busy or you have more one project running is run your project in new port such as 8088 or another free port.

```
php artisan serve --port=8088
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem too, and i succeed solved it in this way:

set: php.ini
variables_order = "GPCS"

Answer (score 0):

I was implicitly specifing a `--host=192.168.100.145:8000` which caused an error trying to connect to `192.168.100.145:8000:8000`

fixed it with `php artisan serve --host=192.168.100.145 --port=8000`

Answer (score -1):

In Ubuntu terminal:

```
sudo su
netstat -plnt
kill -9 PID
```

Answer (score -3):

If you have all your configurations ok in the .env file then you should:

Use the answer from **mayorsanmayor** in this post to kill all php processes. 
Then **php artisan config:clear**

Finally, **php artisan serve**

**Good luck!**