# Unable to start laravel development server on linux

Tags: php, linux, laravel, laravel-artisan

I am using laravel 5 for my project and everything has been working fine but recently I am facing this problem which I done understand.

```
devboy@devboy-hp ~/sonel_ims_project/ims_eneo $ php artisan serve
Laravel development server started on http://localhost:8000/
[Fri Nov 13 12:00:56 2015] Failed to listen on localhost:8000 (reason: Address already in use)
```

I have tried `devboy@devboy-hp ~ $ sudo netstat -plnt` and get

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1840/dnsmasq    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1985/cupsd      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8888          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7563/php-5.6.3  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1656/master     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6966/httpd      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      740/smbd        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6942          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7442/java       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6931/php-5.6.3  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6667            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1539/ircd       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      740/smbd        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:63342         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7442/java       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6966/httpd      
tcp6       0      0 :::21                   :::*                    LISTEN      7337/proftpd: (acce
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      1985/cupsd      
tcp6       0      0 :::3128                 :::*                    LISTEN      1416/squid3     
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      1656/master     
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN      740/smbd        
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      7343/mysqld     
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN      740/smbd
```

Then I change port like so `php artisan serve --port="8888"`
but get similar error like below after a while:

```
Laravel development server started on http://localhost:8888/
[Fri Nov 13 12:01:02 2015] Failed to listen on localhost:8888 (reason: Address already in use)
```

The first time it happened, it was java using port 8000, so I killed the process and started the server and it worked. Upon stopping and restarting, I get the same error. What could be the problem (as I said everything has been working fine except now and I have not done any major update)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly what I did for the problem.

1. I exit PHPStorm
2. `sudo netstat -plnt`
3. `kill 7563 (Process using port 8888)`
4. `kill 6931 (Process using port 8000)`
5. `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart` (Restart my server altogther)
6. `php artisan serve`
7. Launch PhpStorm

Now everything is working fine. What caused the problem anyway?

Answer (score 10):

Your previous deployment in your local is already running that's why you can't run `php artisan serve`. You can solve your issue by following this command in your terminal:

1. `ps -ef | grep php` you'll see this list:

   > gujarat   6690  3500  0 05:55 pts/1    00:00:00 php artisan serve 
   >   gujarat   6694  6690  0 05:55 pts/1    00:00:00 sh -c '/usr/bin/php5'
   >   -S localhost:8000 '/home/gujarat/WebDevelopment/quickstart-basic'/server.php 
   > gujarat  6695  6694  0 05:55 pts/1    00:00:00 /usr/bin/php5 -S localhost:8000
   >   /home/gujarat/WebDevelopment/quickstart-basic/server.php 
   >   
   > gujarat  7436  3500  0 06:26 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto php
2. Now kill it using: `sudo kill 6690` if still exist then use this `sudo kill -9 6690` you'll see this result:

   > [1]+  Killed                  php artisan serve

Now you can serve your local using `php artisan serve` again

Answer (score 3):

please restart apache server

```
sudo apache restart
```

And once again run your project in another port

```
php artisan serve --port=2020
```

Answer (score 1):

Using lsof, you can see what is listening on the port.

```
sudo lsof -i :80
```

Change the 80 to whichever port you're interested.  You need to be root or sudo.

Answer (score 1):

Run this comment

```
sudo netstat -plnt
```

The output will show like this

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name 
tcp       14      0 127.0.0.1:8000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3648/php7.3
```

Then kill the port:8000 using this comment

```
 kill -9 3648
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem might be it didnt stop the expected way previously eg via **CTRL+C** so what you can do is to check for running php processes and kill them 1 by 1.

i) Run `ps -A` from the terminal then identify the php process ids (most of the times they are two)

ii) Run `sudo kill -9 pid#` corresponding to the php pids.

iii) Run `php artisan serve` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

**This can happen when there is already an app running on 127.0.0.1:8000**

You can close that app then it will work or not available on the current host.

OR if you want to run multple apps then use shown below way:

You can use this command to run *`sudo php artisan serve --port=8082`* for Linux

```
                        php artisan serve --port=8082 for window
```