# Failed to listen on localhost:8000 (reason: Cannot assign requested address)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When I run `php artisan serve` on Ubuntu, the Laravel development server tries to start on http://localhost:8000/ but fails with this error:

> [Mon Apr 25 10:28:08 2016] Failed to listen on localhost:8000 (reason: Cannot assign requested address)

My hosts file (`/etc/hosts/`):

```
1 27.0.0.1   localhost
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Is there actually a space between the "1" and "2" in your hosts file?

Comment: The best answers are here https://stackoverflow.com/a/33560446/3041435

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's usually because the port is in already in use, or not available on the current host.

You can use this command to run
**php artisan serve --port=8080**